# Remove CodeIgniter controller name, index.php to just show default controller method names (with hyphens)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'd like to

1. Remove the default controller name from the URL
2. Remove index.php from the URL
3. Convert method_name with underscores to method-name with hyphens

In the following example fudev is the subdirectory off the root, and preview is the directory that codeigniter is in.

Currently: http://devsite.com/fudev/preview/index.php/controllername/method_name.

I wish have:

http://devsite.com/fudev/preview/method-name

Any ideas? I had the following in config/routes.php to change the method name to hyphens

```
$route['controllername/method-name'] = 'controllername/method_name';
```

..But that's only any good when I include controllername, which I want to omit.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance..

Jon.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the url to accept hyphens by extending the Router class.
Create a file called MY_Router.php in application/core (assuming you haven't changed the default extension prefix which is set in your config.

The code for this file is;

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Router extends CI_Router {

    function set_class($class) {
        $this->class = str_replace('-', '_', $class);
    }

    function set_method($method) {
        $this->method = str_replace('-', '_', $method);
    }

    function _validate_request($segments) {
        // Does the requested controller exist in the root folder?
        if (file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.str_replace('-', '_', $segments[0]).'.php')) {
            return $segments;
        }
        // Is the controller in a sub-folder?
        if (is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$segments[0])) {       
            // Set the directory and remove it from the segment array
            $this->set_directory($segments[0]);
            $segments = array_slice($segments, 1);

            if (count($segments) > 0) {
                // Does the requested controller exist in the sub-folder?
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().str_replace('-', '_', $segments[0]).'.php')) {
                    show_404($this->fetch_directory().$segments[0]);
                }
            } else {
                $this->set_class($this->default_controller);
                $this->set_method('index');

                // Does the default controller exist in the sub-folder?
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().$this->default_controller.'.php')) {
                    $this->directory = '';
                    return array();
                }

            }

            return $segments;
        }

        // Can't find the requested controller...
        show_404($segments[0]);
    }
}
```

This will remap all hyphens to underscores for your controllers, no need to mess around with htaccess.

Comment: you'll need the .htaccess to remove the index.php from the url

Comment: yes, sorry - though that was a given, didn't read the question properly. Removing the index.php is a basic thing and is covered loads, no need to repeat it again here.